# VMware wakeup on lan, or prevent from shutdown

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, remote-access

I'm facing with one problem. I have server with VMware and fe virtual machines configured and running. Is there any way to prevent client from shutdown machine ? Or maybe there is an option to turn on machine via lan ? Basicaly sometimes user click shutdown insted of logoff. And our IT has to be involved to switch on the machine to live, since there is no access to VM manager. Does anyone of you had simmmilar problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to handle this.

You could create a vCenter alarm where `If` a VM is powered off, `Then` (advanced action) Power on VM. 
You could also use a configuration management system to ensure the VM is always in a powered on state.

However, since the power change is coming from internal to the VM (aka. from the guest OS), you may want to remove that user's access to power off the system by way of a GPO rule.

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about turn of this option through GPO.